# Restore table state on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin in a project (server-side page). The problem that I have is when I go into the details of a table element (and leave the table page) and then return back, the page number and order is not preserved.

On the server side I can save the page in session and return to the table to send the page Ajax call.

How to return to the state it was in the table after entering item details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option to restore table state on page reload.

For example:

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
   stateSave: true,
  // ... other options ...
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg0aabsn/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: This worked for me. As I have a search form, when I make a new search, I use table.state.clear () function.